# How to exclude capitalized words from spell checking in Vim?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

There are too many acronyms and proper nouns to add to the dictionary. I would like any words that contains a capital letter to be excluded from spell checking. Words are delimited by either a whilespace or special characters (i.e., non-alphabetic characters). Is this possible?

The first part of the answer fails when the lowercase and special characters surround the capitalized word:

```
,jQuery,
, iPad,
/demoMRdogood/
[CSS](css)
`appendTo()`,
```

The current answer gives false positives (excludes from the spellcheck) when the lowercase words are delimited by a special character. Here are the examples:

```
(async)
leetcode, eulerproject,
```

The bounty is for the person who fixes this problem.

Comment: Can you give examples of what capitalized words are? Because it seems you don't like the answer that is already given. And it does what you want. (ie all words that start with a capital letter) or least the first one does.

Comment: Okay I changed the question a bit. I have included cases where the current answer fails.

Comment: Whats wrong with the first one? `:syn match myExCapitalWords +\<[A-Z]\w*\>+ contains=@NoSpell` This says all of those are spelled wrong.

Comment: I added the cases where the first one fails. Sorry I know I seem to be nitpicking, but I wanted a perfect solution. I will add more cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me. This passes the cases I mentioned in the question:

```
syn match myExCapitalWords +\<\w*[A-Z]\K*\>+ contains=@NoSpell
```

Here is an alternative solution that uses `\S` instead of `\K`. The alternative solution excludes characters that are in the parenthesis and are preceded by a capitalized letter. Since it is more lenient, it works better for URLs:

```
syn match myExCapitalWords +\<\w*[A-Z]\S*\>+ contains=@NoSpell
```

---

### Exclude "'s" from the spellcheck

`s` after an apostrophe is considered a misspelled letter regardless of the solution above. a quick solution is to add `s` to your dictionary or add a case for that:

```
syn match myExCapitalWords +\<\w*[A-Z]\K*\>\|'s+ contains=@NoSpell
```

This was not part the question, but this is a common case for spell checking process so I mentioned it here.

Comment: If I use this in a .c file, then it removes the color-coding of the strings i.e., usually, strings are highlighted differently in C-code, and if I use the above vim command then it removes that code color-coding!.

Answer (score 12):

You can try this command:

```
:syn match myExCapitalWords +\<[A-Z]\w*\>+ contains=@NoSpell
```

The above command instructs Vim to handle every pattern described by `\<[A-Z]\w*\>` as part of the `@NoSpell` cluster. Items of the `@NoSpell` cluster aren’t spell checked.

If you further want to exclude all words from spell checking that contain at least one non-alphabetic character you can invoke the following command:

```
:syn match myExNonWords +\<\p*[^A-Za-z \t]\p*\>+ contains=@NoSpell
```

Type `:h spell-syntax` for more information.

Comment: This almost works for me. In case when the word has a non-alphabet character before or after, the spell check still kicks in. I tried to put conditionals for the non-Alphabet characters before and after, but it is not working as I expect it to. And if I take away the 'beginning of word' or the 'end of word' markers the matching do not work at all.

Comment: Is it possible to extend this so that words in the beginning of sentences do not get matched? I tried with `+\v(\. )@!<\u\w*>+`, but it didn't work.