# removing spell syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, spell-checking

This question is a sequel question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196399/exclude-capitlized-words-from-vim-spell-check). I have the following script that removes capitalized words from vim spell check.

```
syn match myExCapitalWords +\<\w*[A-Z]\K*\>+ contains=@NoSpell
```

But it works only if I do `syn clear` first. But then all other highlighting (e.g. markdown) gets lost. I went through `syn list` to see what might be causing the conflict, but now I am out of clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're extending arbitrary syntaxes with your `myExCapitalWords` group. Whether / in which syntax items that works depends on the underlying syntax. Unfortunately, it is not possible to extend arbitrary syntaxes in a blanket way. That's why you're seeing problems that can only be solved via `:syn clear` (which gets rid of the underlying syntax).

A syntax contains multiple groups, some of which are usually `contained=` in others. If you introduce a new syntax, it will only apply to where no other syntax group already matches. You can force your group into others via `containedin=TOP` or even `containedin=ALL`, but that overlay may prevent other original groups from matching, and causes strange effects because their own `contains=` or `nextgroup=` now don't apply.

So, unfortunately, there's no general solution for this. If you're only interested in a few syntaxes, you can tweak your one-liner to make it cooperate with the underlying syntax (e.g. try `containedin={syntaxName}Comment{s}`), but there's no generally applicable solution.

Comment: So even if I spend a ton of time to make this work, if syntax highlighting changes due to a new plugin, it will break right? I am guessing if there was a solution that does not use `syn` you would have told me already. Thanks Ingo, like always, a great answer.

Comment: If you mean new plugin version by "new plugin", I wouldn't worry too much about that. Most are pretty stable. You need to adapt for additional languages / filetypes, though.

Comment: There's the `matchadd()` alternative to syntax, but it won't work in this case (and is cumbersome to apply, anyway), because spell checking is connected to `syn`, unfortunately.