# Exclude words with numbers from spellcheck in vim

Tags: regex, vim

Following [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18196613/1655567) I would like to ignore words with numbers that are of the following format:

```
AB12
AB2
CD98
..
```

this is achieved with use of the following regex:

```
[A-Z]{2}\d{1,}
```

*[(regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/NpTwUn/1)*

The syntax I'm trying:

```
:syn match ignoredCapitalWords +[A-Z]{2}\d{1,}+ contains=@NoSpell
```

does not seem to be generating the desired results as the words remain marked as potentially misspelled:

[image: wrong misspelling highlight]

*How can I correctly used the previously generated regex to exclude the desired patterns from regex?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php regex engine is not vim regex engine. When you doubt your syntax pattern is right just create a new buffer with desired contents and then use `/` command. The given pattern throws an error, you just have to escape each `{` character with backslash. So, the correct pattern is: `[A-Z]\{2}\d\{1,}`. Never used `@NoSpell` but the pattern works.